# Yii2: Error In Composer

Tags: yii2, composer-php

Why i got error message in my composer after i run composer update in my composer.json: i update this require `"yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.4",` to `"yiisoft/yii2": "dev-master",` and then i want to change back to `"yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.4"`..i got this message:

[image]

anyone who know how fix this problem....

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should run following command first to install the composer-asset-plugin:

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0"
```

You also need to add the following code to your project's `composer.json` file:

```
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
```

Comment: it will definitely not ruin your other extension

Comment: this command: php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0" and also i add to my composer                                                            "extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}